# Building SSIS solution using visual studio online build definition... .dtproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2012, msbuild

I've created a build definition via visual studio online that builds an SSIS project (dtproj).  The build appears to succeed but there is a warning that appears stating "dtproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built".

SSDT has been installed on the build server.

Does anyone have any ideas why this warning would be showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSBuild cannot build the project file format that SSDT uses. It is a pre-msbuild visuals studio format.

There's a hacky way to [create an msbuild project that performs the necessary tasks](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) but the easiest way is not not use MSBuild for this project but build it via the visual studio command line [`devenv.exe /build`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx). Since this builds from visual studio, it understands all project file formats and has the necessary SSDT plugins.

Comment: Hi Martin,
It does work fine using visual studio 2015.  however, we build and deploy via visual studio online and build definitions.

Comment: You should be able to use `devenv.exe` as well in VSTS / build servers. You just cannot use the msbuild-based tasks in VSTS but use a command line step. There is a feature request for a "build with visual studio task" that uses devenv.exe at https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/946

Comment: Please vote here if you think it's about time for MSBuild to support SSxS projects: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html