# MSBuild DeploymentModel unrecognised error in deploying SSIS package

Tags: tfs, ssis, msbuild, tfsbuild

I created a PowerShell script to automate deployment for SSIS projects and used it in a custom TFS task. Within this task I used a msbuild step to build the SSIS project which keeps failing with this error:

> Error MSB4067: The element DeploymentModel beneath element Project
>   is unrecognized.

I built the SSIS projects in visual studio 2015 just fine. I have tried msbuild version 12.0 and 15.0 and they both have the same error. 
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building SSIS solution using visual studio online build definition... .dtproj is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410829/building-ssis-solution-using-visual-studio-online-build-definition-dtproj-is)

Comment: Please vote here if you think it's about time for MSBuild to support SSxS projects: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/523612/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild.html

Comment: [MS finally released a stand alone devops tool for building SSIS projects.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15) Download link at bottom of page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build your SSIS projects via VS, actually is calling [`/Build (devenv.exe)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx), not directly using MSBuild.

There is no build-in task that supports building via `devenv.exe`.Still in the backlog. More details please refer: ["Visual Studio Build" build step that actually invokes devenv.com instead of msbuild?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/946)

As a workaround, you could try to use 3-party extension task [SSIS Build & Deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TG.VSTS-SSIS#review-details) for now.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using powershell to invoke devenv.com which on the build server. works great. Thanks again for your help.