# MSBuild throws error of DeploymentModel for SSIS project

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, msbuild

I'm trying to build VS (version 2019) SSIS project with MSbuild in CMD, but gets error:
`The element DeploymentModel beneath element Project is unrecognized.`

It worked only after I used this WA from 2017:

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2064#issuecomment-315875143

I was wondering if there is already solution for it or this is just the way it works?
another answer which might be relevant:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275125/14976099

I'm asking again as when using devenv you need Visual Studio installed on your computer, and for MSBuild you only need to have the .NET framework installed (which is where I'm hoping to get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my understating, the answer is here and was released few months ago:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-ssis-ssrs-ssas-in-msbuild/523612#T-N1246482